# Import Pydev Project into Eclipse on a new machine

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, pydev

I need to install an existing pydev project into Eclipse on a new machine.  (Actually it is the same machine, but re-imaged.)  The new machine has Eclipse Neon.  I was using an older version previously.

My data has all been copied over.  I have the folder where the project lived on my old machine, which includes the `.project` and `.pydevproject` files.  I used the Import wizard to import it, but I don't see my run configurations, pythonpath, etc.

Where might those be stored on my old machine, and can I recover them easily without setting them up again by hand?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I was opening Eclipse in the wrong workspace.  When I found the correct workspace for that project (by looking for the .metadata file on my C drive) everything was all set (and I didn't have to import the project at all).

I was going to delete the question, but figured instead I'd answer in case this helps someone else.